# How to get everything after an '@'-selector in the url in php

Tags: php

I'm coding a CDN in PHP, it works this far, but I want to choose different versions by adding an '@' with the version behind it. How do I get the version String after the '@'.
Example: https://cdn.steven2105.de/jquery@3.3.0

```php
<?php
$error = false;

$path = str_replace("/", "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

switch($path) {
    case "jquery":
        $toOpen = "jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js";
        break;
    case "jquery@3.3.0":
        $toOpen = "jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js";
        break;
    case "vue":
        $toOpen = "vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js";
        break;
    case "bootstrap-css":
        $toOpen = "bootstrap/4.3.1/bootstrap.min.css";
        break;
    case "bootstrap-js":
        $toOpen = "bootstrap/4.3.1/bootstrap.min.js";
        break;
    case "baguettebox-css":
        $toOpen = "baguettebox/1.11.0/baguettebox.min.css";
        break;
    case "baguettebox-js":
        $toOpen = "baguettebox/1.11.0/baguettebox.min.js";
        break;
    case "popper":
        $toOpen = "popper/1.14.7/popper.min.js";
        break;
    default:
        $error = true;
        break;
}

if (!$error) { 
    header("Location: https://cdn.steven2105.de/libs/$toOpen");
} else {
    include_once "website.php";
}
```

EDIT: What should I do now? It doesn't work.

I have different libaries in the path https://cdn.steven2105.de/libs/ e.g. https://cdn.steven2105.de/libs/jquery with files in it such like https://cdn.steven2105.de/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js. I'd like to access these links with a shorter prefix like https://cdn.steven2105.de/jquery@3.3.1. If I use the '@' character it should redirect to the version in the directory https://cdn.steven2105.de/libs/jquery/ and if it's without the '@' it should redirect to the latest version.

What is the easiest way?

Comment: `list( $before, $after )=explode('@', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );`?

Comment: Why not do it the normal way? `https://cdn.steven2105.de/jquery?version=3.3.0` You must have a good reason for this.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I can't answer why, but this is a pretty common URL-style for CDNs. If anything, a query string is going to be more fiddly to handle in this case, because you've got to parse the path part anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode` function for this. It Outputs as an array and fetch it.

```
<?php

$URL = ' https://cdn.steven2105.de/jquery@3.3.0';
$Result = explode('@', $URL);
echo("<pre>");print_r($Result[1]);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using PHP you could probably fix this with webserver configuration.

Rewrite rules in Apache (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html) should do the trick. I would expect Nginx to offer similar functionality.

If you use Apache or Nginx to do this for you it will be way faster as you won't have the overhead of running a PHP script.

Comment: What OP has shown has not only the overhead of the script, but that of the _external_ redirect as well, so two HTTP requests for each such external resource, instead of one … which made it a rather unclever thing to begin with. So yeah, _internal_ rewriting would be much preferable.

Comment: Yes, that is true as well.